# Writing general script using open('file', 'r')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script where I first read a file using 
`with open('file', 'r') as file`,
do some operation, and then write it to a new file using
`with open('newfile', 'w') as newfile`.

My question is, what do I need to change in the script to make it general for a number of files, so that I can just call the script with the file name from the terminal like `python3 script.py file.ext`? Also, is there a way to write the output back into the original file using this method?

Comment: Your question seems to be "how do I take command line input in Python?", which you could easily search for online.

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is:

```
import sys
file=open(sys.argv[1], "r")
newfile=open("example.txt", "w")
content=file.read()
#do stuff to content here such as content=content.upper()
newfile.write(content)
```

If you inputted into the command line:

```
python script.py aaaaaa.txt
```

Then the file you set as the output would have the edited content of aaaaaa.txt

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but if I run the script on _n_ files at the same time, I would like that there are _n_ output files as well. That is why i was trying to use `fileinput` and writing the output back in the original file

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/blob/master/new_no_first-last.py) is the script if you want to take a look at it